# Move a file with Google-Drive-API

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

Is it possible to explicitly move a file through python's googleapiclient module? I want to create the following function, given a file, original path and destination path:

```
def move_file(service, filename, init_drive_path, drive_path, copy=False):
    """Moves a file in Google Drive from one location to another.

    service: Drive API service instance.
    filename (string): full name of file on drive
    init_drive_path (string): initial file location on Drive
    drive_path (string): the file path to move the file in on Drive
    copy (boolean): file should be saved in both locations

    Returns nothing.
    """
```

Currently I have been executing this through manually downloading the file and then re-uploading it to the desired location, however this is not practical for big files and seems like a work-around method anyway.

[Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) for the methods available on the google-drive-api.

---

EDIT See solution below:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Found it here.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) You just need to retrieve the file and folder ID and then use the update method. The remove_parents parameter can be excluded if you want to leave a copy of the file in the old folder(s)

```py
    file_id = '***'
    folder_id = '***'

    # Retrieve the existing parents to remove
    file = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='parents').execute()
    previous_parents = ",".join(file.get('parents'))

    # Move the file to the new folder
    file = drive_service.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        addParents=folder_id,
        removeParents=previous_parents,
        fields='id, parents'
    ).execute()
```

(Note I have not included my basic helper functions _getFileId and _getFolderId) So my original function will look something like:

```py
    def move_file(service, filename, init_drive_path, drive_path, copy=False):
        """Moves a file in Google Drive from one location to another.
    
            service: Drive API service instance.
            'filename' (string): file path on local machine, or a bytestream
            to use as a file.
            'init_drive_path' (string): the file path the file was initially in on Google
            Drive (in <folder>/<folder>/<folder> format).
            'drive_path' (string): the file path to move the file in on Google
            Drive (in <folder>/<folder>/<folder> format).
            'copy' (boolean): file should be saved in both locations
    
            Returns nothing.
        """
        file_id = _getFileId(service, filename, init_drive_path)
        folder_id = _getFolderId(service, drive_path)
    
        if not file_id or not folder_id:
            raise Exception('Did not find file specefied: {}/{}'.format(init_drive_path, filename))
    
        file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='parents').execute()
        
        if copy:
            previous_parents = ''
        else:
            previous_parents = ",".join(file.get('parents'))

        file = service.files().update(
            fileId=file_id,
            addParents=folder_id,
            removeParents=previous_parents,
            fields='id, parents'
        ).execute()
```